# Bind UISwitch's state to NSUserDefaults with ReactiveCocoa

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults, uiswitch, reactive-cocoa

How can I bind `UISwitch.on` with the value for a key in `NSUserDefaults`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can bind them (two-way binding) by following:

```
RACChannelTerminal *switchTerminal = self.someSwitch.rac_newOnChannel;
RACChannelTerminal *defaultsTerminal = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] rac_channelTerminalForKey:@"someBoolKey"];

[switchTerminal subscribe:defaultsTerminal];
[defaultsTerminal subscribe:switchTerminal];
```

The switch's `on` state starts with the value from the user defaults or `NO`.